# Clean up / refactor this store() method

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and trying to figure out how I can reduce/refactor this `store()` call in my `SessionController`.

Basically, the `SessionController` is used to authenticate a user against an LDAP server (using [wells/l4-ldap-ntlm](https://github.com/wells/l4-ldap-ntlm) instead of the default auth driver)

On LDAP auth success, it then checks if the user has an account/profile for this webapp. If they do not, it creates it. If they already have one, it just logs them in (user/profile only created on first login).

If LDAP auth fails, it redirects back to the login page.

I know this is a lengthy method for a controller, so I want to know the best practices for:

1. Refactoring this code out, so the controller is cleaner, and adhering to the "single responsibility" rule.
2. I need to use LDAP just for authentication, but I also want to store information for this webapp that is not stored in LDAP. Right now I am creating a `User` and a `Profile` model, but I don't know a good way to "link" them to the LDAP authenticated user once logged in.

```
public function store()
{
    // store credentials
    $input = Input::all();

    // attempt authentication
    $attempt = Auth::attempt([
        'username' => $input['user'],
        'password' => $input['pass']
    ]);

    if ($attempt) {
        // LDAP auth success
        $un   = Auth::user()->username;
        $role = Auth::user()->type;

        // check if user exists, creating a user and profile if they do not.
        try {
            $user = User::whereUsername($un)->firstOrFail();
        } 
        catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            $user = User::create(['username'=>$un]);
            $user->roles()->attach( $role );
            $user->createProfile();
        }

        // redirect
        return Redirect::intended('/profile')
                        ->with('flash_message', 'welcome, ' . $un);
    }
    else {
        // LDAP auth failed.
        return Redirect::back()
                        ->with('flash_message', 'The credentials you entered were invalid. Please try again.')
                        ->withInput();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let me get this right (I have no experience working with an LDAP): The `Auth` class you're first using for `$attempt` is actually the LDAP library you're implementing?

I don't think I understand the logic in your code. You attempt to log in to the user, and if they successfully login, you check to see if the user exists? I must be misunderstanding something.

Well, assuming you know how exactly this works, I'll just point out a couple refactor points I can see:

- In terms of breaking this apart into responsibilities: your method handles both authentication and registration. I can imagine registration being handled in another method.
- I doubt you need to flash forward this entire parameter: `'welcome, ' . $un`. Have your Blade file check for the flash and display "welcome, ". Since you're only sending one, just pass through `$un`. Either that or make it an array and pass two values: type of flash, and message.
- Speaking of `$un`. There are better variable names, give yours some meaning and quality to them.
- You can manage to un-nest your code a little:

> ```
> if ($attempt) {
>     ...
> } else {
>     return Redirect...
> }
> ```

This piece could really just be:

```
if (!$attempt) {
    return Redirect...
}

// *What used to be inside the if*
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a bunch for the input!

It is a little strange, but essentially I just use LDAP for authentication with our systems (ie username and password). On successful auth, LDAP only returns me the username, but not other information I Need (name, location, etc). So to get around this I'm essentially creating a "profile" for my system, which is mapped to their LDAP username (basically instead of using an integer for relational ID, I'm using the LDAP username).